# How can a computed column value be calculated and then inserted into database at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, listview, calculated-columns

How can i write a insert query in my aspx page like following???

```
insert into tablname(field1 ,field2, field3)values(@field1,@field2,@field1-@field2)
```

Here I have made **field3** a computed column in database as well  which is **field1 -field2** in database. Values inserted in fields are in textbox so i want at runtime to calculate difference two textboxes and then insert that value in database. How can i achieve this??

Comment: check the answer you need to crete colunted column in your table that will do work for you ...

Comment: is that work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include field 3 in your insert.

[From MSDN: Unless otherwise specified, computed columns are virtual columns that are not physically stored in the table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

So you can display the computed value on your form but when you do the actual insert into the database just insert the 2 values. The value for field3 will be computed when you query the table.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but I would suggest you to create a stored procedure with two parameters `@field1` and `@field2` and perform the insert statement from there, like you can create a local variable within the stored procedure which will compute the value `@field3 = @field1 - @field2` and submit the values `(@field1, @field2, @field3)`

```
create table test22(field1 int, field2 int, field3 int)

create proc inserttest22
    @field1 int,
    @field2 int
as
    declare @field3 int

    set @field3 = @field1 - @field2

    insert into test22 values (@field1, @field2, @field3)
go
```